# Finding the smallest integer for which a function is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a quadratic function in $n$, $f(n)$. I want to find out the smallest positive $n$ for which $f(n)$ is composite. Outside of exhaustive search, is there a way to solve this?

Example: $f(n) = n^2 + n + 17$

Preferably, please just provide a hint to point me in the right direction instead of working out the example.

Comment: This is too vague.  There's no universal method...we need to know more about the function.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is too broad.  Please edit your post to add detail.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: What is the broad class of functions you are interested in? Only quadratics? [edit] again to tell us a lot more about the question.

Comment: For the given example, we can see that $f(17)$ is composite so you only have to search for $n\in \{0,1,\cdots, 16\}$.

Comment: @EthanBolker. Edited

Comment: @lulu. I don't think your vote makes sense. This is an elementary problem in number theory. I initially did not want to give an example because I want to solve it myself. All I am looking for is a hint or if there is none, indicate as much so I don't waste time looking for a solution that does not exist. To downvote it even after I gave a concrete example makes no sense. Anyway, downvote to your hearts content.

Comment: The downvote preceded your example.  Post example, I provided a simple means of solution.

Comment: I have retracted the downvote, though I still think it is a poor question. The example did improve it.  As I and others have remarked, there is no general method for solving problems of this type.  If you intended to restrict only to the quadratic in your example, that's a very different question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a general method, but brute force is not likely to be slow. $f$ evaluated at its constant term is clearly composite. The first composite occurs no later than the smallest factor of the constant term.

You can speed up a brute force search since the successive values of a quadratic function are in arithmetic progression, so can be found with addition rather than multiplication.

**Edit** in response to comment.

If $f$ has constant term $1$ then look for composite values for $g$, where
$$
g(x) = f(x+1).
$$

Comment: $f$ evaluated at constant term is only composite if the constant term $> 1$

Comment: @SouverainPremier True. If that case is particularly important, say so in the question.

Comment: Thank you @Ethan Bolker